# Core Data Migration from Integer 16 to Transformable

Tags: ios, core-data

In my application, I have a core data entity with an attribute, `value`. I would like to change the type of this attribute from `Integer 16` to `Transformable` in my upcoming release.

Now, when setting up my persistent store coordinator, I include the following as options:

```
let options: [NSString: Bool] = [
            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options) ...
```

Now, I've created a second version of my core data model which includes the update to the `value` attribute, and no other changes. When I attemp to build, I get the following errors:

```
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite ... Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model
```

and further down, this:

```
Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration ... Source and destination attribute types are incompatible.
```

So apparently CoreData can't map from the Integer 16 to Transformable automatically? How can I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no obvious rule for how to convert an existing integer value to a binary blob, so Core Data throws up it's hands here and says it doesn't know what you want it to do. Converting an attribute to a different data type requires more work on your part.

If you are actually converting data-- as in, you want the new binary `value` to be somehow derived from the old integer `value`-- then you need to create a mapping model and do migration the relatively-hard way. Part of this will involve you making the integer-to-binary conversion. There's a lot to know here so I'll refer you to [Apple's Core Data migration guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) for more information.

**However** if the new binary `value` is independent of the old integer `value`-- meaning that the new data **is not derived** from the old data but is a complete replacement for it-- you can keep things simple. If that's the case, don't rename the attribute. Create a new attribute with a different name, `valueBlob` or whatever, and delete the `value` attribute. Automatic lightweight migration can handle adding and removing attributes, so it could handle that change.

Comment: You can also chain multiple lightweight migrations in sequence to perform a more complicated migration without going through the heavy-weight path.  In this particular case, you can do what Tom suggested in the second part, and create a second attribute which uses the data from the integers value, and delete the integer value attribute.  Then, you can have a subsequent lightweight migration that renames the valueBlob attribute back to value.  This may be overkill for this particular example, but can be useful for avoiding the heavyweight migration path.